# How do I remove a cmd variable?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Let's say I execute the following in the CMD shell:

```
SET "FOO=bar"
```

Is there a way to undefine this variable, other than recycling the CMD shell?

Comment: Do you **really** mean MS-DOS (which has been dead for at least 10 years or so) - or do you say *MS-DOS* but really mean the Windows command line (`cmd.exe`) ??

Comment: Likely, but it doesn't really matter for that question...

Comment: Marc's right. This is not the MS-DOS shell. People never learn that this is a big difference.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, Indeed, your `set var=` answer works under MS-DOS 6.22 command.com just the same as it does under Windows cmd.exe. (However, unlike Windows, putting double quotes around the var= doesn't work, instead it creates an environment variable whose name starts with a double quote.)

Answer (score 156):

Yes, you can unset it with

```
set FOO=
```

Or explicitly using:

```
set "FOO="
```

Ensure no trailing extraneous (invisible) characters come after the `=` sign. That is:

- `set FOO=` is different from `set FOO=`      .

Comment: For me it only worked like so: $Env:FOO = ""

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast That's the right command in PowerShell, `set FOO` is for `cmd`.

Comment: the second one is good since `set "FOO="      ` will still unset it.

Answer (score 34):

A secure way to unset the variable is to use also quotes, then there aren't problems with trailing spaces.

```
set FOO=bar
echo %FOO%
set "FOO=" text after the last quote is ignored
echo %FOO%
```

Answer (score 14):

another method

```
@Echo oFF

setlocal
set FOO=bar
echo %FOO%
endlocal

echo %FOO%

pause
```

Note: This would not work on an interactive command prompt. But works in batch script.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me in my Windows 7 CMD shell:

```
set FOO=bar
echo %FOO% // bar
set FOO=
echo %FOO% // empty; calling "set" no longer lists it
```

Comment: Spaces are significant in the `set` command. If you try `set FOO = bar` and then try `set FOO=`, it won't unset 'FOO '. For some reason, though, they aren't (as?) significant inside `% %`.

Comment: The trailing space is also important.  Sorry for the edit, I thought your rep said 270, not 270k... oops.  I often edit answers when rep suggests the user isn't coming back.  Obviously not the case here.  My mistake.

Comment: @chappjs no problem, thanks for the edit! Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

I would offer the following only as a comment, but I think it's important enough to stand on its own.

A lot of the previous answers mentioned that one needs to beware of trailing spaces; and for sure that is true.  However I've found that sometimes trailing spaces just want to get in there no matter what - particularly if you are doing a command line one-liner and need the space as a command separator.

This is the solution to that problem:

```
SET FOO=Bar
echo %FOO%
:: outputs Bar
SET "FOO="
echo %FOO%
:: outputs %FOO%
```

By wrapping the declaration in double quotes that way, the spacing issue can be avoided entirely.  This can also really useful when variables are created by  concatenating to eliminate spaces in between - for example - paths, e.g:

```
SET A=c:\users\ && SET D=Daniel
SET P="%a%%d%"
ECHO %P%
:: outputs "C:\Users\ Daniel"
:: Notice the undesirable space there
```