# Passing null string value via environment variable to TSQL script

Tags: t-sql, environment-variables, sqlcmd, dereference, null-string

I have a DOS batch file I want to use to invoke a TSQL program.
I want to pass the names of the databases to use.  This seems to work.
I want to pass the PREFIXES for the names of the tables I want to work with.
So for test tables I want to pass the name of a prefix to use the test table.

```
set svr=myserver
rem set db=myTESTdatabasename
set db=mydatabasename
rem set tp=TEST
set tp=
sqlcmd -S %svr% -d somename -i test01.sql
```

test01.sql looks like this:

```
use $(db)
go

select top 10 * into $(db).dbo.$(tp)dsttbl from $(db).dbo.$(tp)srctbl
```

It works fine for the test stuff, but for the real stuff, I just want to set the value of tp to null so that it will use the real table name and not the bogus table name.

The reason I'm doing this is because I don't know the names of everything that will be used on the actual databases.  I'm trying to make it generic so I don't have to do a bunch of search replaces on what will be a very large sql program (the real sql program is already hundreds of lines).

In the test case, this would resolve to

```
select top 10 * into myTESTdatabasename.dbo.TESTdsttbl from myTESTdatabasename.dbo.TESTsrctbl
```

For the production runs, it should resolve to

```
select top 10 * into mydatabasename.dbo.dsttbl from mydatabasename.dbo.srctbl
```

The problem seems that it doesn't like null values for $(tp), or perhaps that it's getting an undefined variable.

Comment: What does rhe 'Real table' mean? Do you mean dbo schema. In which case just set tp=dbo. Also [Use sqlcmd with Scripting Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) : Does the /V command line option work?

Comment: good question. let me edit to clear that up.

Comment: Maybe this is clearer.

Comment: did the /V "tp=" offer any help?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part of the comment. I'll try.

Comment: set /v "tp=" does not work. By the time it gets to the SQL, it still says the variable is undefined.

Comment: What about declaring a variable `declare @prefix nvarchar(50)` and then `select @prefix=ISNULL($(tp), '')` and then using dynamic SQL using the sp_executesql sp?

Comment: I've moved on to another part of the program for the time ... when I get back to that I'll try that solution. tx, tff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented some with the syntax and as Preet Sangha pointed out you should use the /V command line option.

The reason is that setting a variable to the empty string in a batch script [undefines it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219672/how-to-undefine-an-ms-dos-variable).

If you want to set the database name in the top of the batch file you can still use set, like this:

```
set db_to_use=
```

Then you can use this (undefined) variable in the sqlcmd using the /V option:

```
sqlcmd -S %svr% -d somename -v db="%db_to_use%" -i test01.sql
```

...or you can just set the value directly in the sqlcmd line:

```
sqlcmd -S %svr% -d somename -v db="" -i test01.sql
```